# Using Spring RestTemplate, how can I log the response when there is an error?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring RestTemplate could set the errorHandler, which has the methods for handling errors. I have an error handler like this

```
try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientHttpResponse.getBody()))) {
     final String response = buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
     System.out.println(response);
  }
```

but it always tell me that the input stream is close. Is this a bug or do I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default error handler of RestTemplate `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` already reads the response body and sets it in the `HttpStatusCodeException` object that it throws.

```
try {
    restTemplate.getForObject("http://...", String.class);
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    System.out.println("Received error: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

If you want to always log the response body on error without requiring to catch `HttpStatusCodeException`, you can extend the default error handler.

```
public static class LoggingErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        try {
            super.handleError(response);
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            System.out.println("Error response body is " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the above error handler while instantiating rest template.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new LoggingErrorHandler());
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://...", String.class);
```